# Ubuntu intermittent network connection, ARP-related

Tags: linux, networking, router, arp

Sorry if the title is too vague, but I cannot pin-point the real problem so hard to phrase it. Here's the description.

Computer A, connected to enterprise network using Windows OS, working fine. But it got intermittent connection problem running Ubuntu 15.10. Observations are:

- The connection is never truly lost, it just hangs for 1 minute or 2, then resumes, but breaks any ssh session along the way.
- This problem is not peculiar to myself, but common to a number of computers running linux-based OS in my workplace. It should not be my misconfiguration. All Windows and a small proportion of linux computers can connect to Internet just fine. So it can be a software or kernel conflict undergoing with the network setting in my workplace.
- The gateway is actually HSRP-enabled Cisco routers. They broadcast a 10.1.1.1 address, but `traceroute google.com` implies the server that did the routing is 10.1.1.2.
- By constantly pinging 10.1.1.1 per second, all out-going packets are successfully sent. But during down time, no ICMP response packet is heard.
- By inspecting the packets, the MAC address of the ICMP packets, no matter in up time or down time, are correctly set to the same value.
- Running `arp -an` gives the same arp table in both down time and up time.
- It looks as if everything should work fine, but it isn't always true. I'm totally clueless except the following finding:
- There is always a clear indication of the coming of a new round of up time --- **An ARP reply from 10.1.1.1**, but only giving the same MAC I already have in ARP cache. When the network becomes available, one can always find an ARP reply several milliseconds prior to that transition moment.
- There is no prominent evidence of when the network will go from up time to down time, unfortunately.

My question is:

How do I proceed to troubleshoot the problem? Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks for reading my verbose description and don't hesitate to request extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the cause of this problem is IP conflict. My PC's IP conflicts with another device, specifically IP telephone, in the same subnet. Since the phone is not always active, so my PC can work most of the time. But when it becomes active, the gateway will recognize its MAC address and drop any ICMP packet from my side.